# MongoDB Replica Set Write Concern Behavior

Tags: mongodb

Apologize if this has been answered but my googling skills seem to be at an all time low:

Imagine a 3 node replica set with write concern of 3 and Journal set to 0.

Do the secondaries commit the data to their journal before returning a success code to the primary?  Or is the data simply committed to memory on the secondaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your described situation, with journaling off and the write concern set to 3 in a 3-node replica set (including primary), your WriteConcern of 3 would just require acknowledgement from each replica set that the data has been written to memory.

from [these](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/write-concern/#j-option) docs, you can infer what happens if 'j' is *not* set based on what happens when it is set, but it's version-specific:

> Requests acknowledgement that the mongod instances, as specified in
>   the w: , have written to the on-disk journal. j: true does not
>   by itself guarantee that the write will not be rolled back due to
>   replica set primary failover.
>
> Changed in version 3.2: With j: true, MongoDB returns only after the
>   requested number of members, including the primary, have written to
>   the journal. Previously j: true write concern in a replica set only
>   requires the primary to write to the journal, regardless of the w:
>    write concern.